# Walk a list without creating unneeded object

Tags: python, loops, iteration, list-comprehension

I usually do this:

```
[worker.do_work() for worker in workers]
```

This has the advantage of being very readable and contained in a single line, but the problem of creating an object (a list) which I do not need, which means garbage collection is unnecessarily triggered.

The obvious alternative:

```
for worker in workers:
    worker.do_work()
```

Is also quite readable, but uses two lines.

Is there a single-line way of achieving the same result, without creating unnecessary objects?

Comment: Why do you care about doing it in one line?

Comment: @BrenBarn I do it very often, and I want to have my code as reduced as possible, while keeping it readable.

Comment: `for worker in workers: worker.do_work()` works as a one liner...

Comment: @KenY-N not PEP8 compliant

Comment: The one-liner style is listed as a "rather not" rather than "definitely not".

Comment: @DanielGonzalez Neither is the list comp with side effects... I'm sure

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I fully trust you on that, but I would like to see an explanation of the rationale behind it. Do you have a link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, there is.

```
def doLotsOfWork(wks):
    for w in wks:
        w.do_work()
```

And now, your "one liner":

```
doLotsOfWork(workers)
```

In short, there's no "shorter" (or better way) besides using a `for` loop. I'd advise you not to use the list comprehension because it uses side effects - that's code smell.

Comment: Haha. And here I got a shock reading the first line "SURE THERE IS"

Comment: @KaushikNP Yes, this was the anticlimax. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

"GC" in python is quite different from java. A ref-count decrement is much much cheaper than mark-and-sweep. Benchmark it, then decide if you're placing too much emphasis on a small cost.

To make it a one liner, simply define a helper function and then it's a single line to invoke it. Bury the function in an imported library if convenient.

Comment: What do you mean by "helper function". Can you show sample code?

Comment: Never mind, I understand what you mean. I wonder if adding function calling overhead is even worse than kicking the GC.

Comment: I don't understand why you're wondering about the cost of this or that. Bench it and see. Post the timing figures here.